# Mediawiki extension "wikidiff2" not working (diffs are empty)

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-extension

I have a problem where the diffs on a MediaWiki that I'm responsible for [are always empty](https://wiki.haskell.org/index.php?title=Android&diff=prev&oldid=61120).

`$wgExternalDiffEngine` is not set in my `LocalSettings.php`, so it should be defaulting to `false`, which is "wikidiff2 if available, PHP implementation else."

However, `wikidiff2` does *appear* to be available.  The contents of `/etc/php5/mods-available/wikidiff2.ini` are:

```
extension=wikidiff2.so
```

and `wikidiff2.so` exists in `/usr/lib/php5/20121212`.

If I go to [`Special:Version`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Special:Version), under "Installed extensions", there is "Wikidiff2 (Version )".  So that suggests that it is installed, but somehow isn't working, since it can't even identify what version it is.

I enabled logging and then looked in the log file and saw:

```
wfShellExec: 'wikidiff2' '/home/web/wikidata/upload/tmp/diff_f9tuWC' '/home/web/wikidata/upload/tmp/diff_TsMWXK'
Possibly missing executable file: 'wikidiff2' '/home/web/wikidata/upload/tmp/diff_f9tuWC' '/home/web/wikidata/upload/tmp/diff_TsMWXK'
```

That suggests that somehow it is trying to run an executable named `wikidiff2`, rather than using the `wikidiff2.so` extension.  Why?

I just inherited this responsibility recently, so unfortunately I don't know how the server got into the state it is currently in.  Any ideas what might be going on, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by putting:

```
$wgExternalDiffEngine = false;
```

in `LocalSettings.php`.  This puzzles me, since it wasn't being set in `LocalSettings.php`, and `false` is supposed to be the default.  But I guess it was being set somewhere else?